# aptana - changing font-size of code and turning on class assistant

Tags: aptana, font-size

I've recently moved from dreamweaver to aptana and tried to make aptana as similiar as possible;)

Lots of changes are done but I still can't find the way to make code font smaller (in dreamweaver code is much more legible cos font is not so big)

and much more important: is there a way to turn on a class suggestion? 
You know - when you have got millions of custom classes and for example you type:

I can't fint it anywhere;( Any help appreciate:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Giuseppe R is correct. That is the general method for changing fonts in Eclipse and Aptana Studio 2.

In Aptana Studio 3 and Titanium Studio, you can edit the text editor/Terminal/console font by going to `Window` > `Preferences` > `Aptana Studio` > `Themes`.

Answer (score 24):

A late reply but at least it may be useful if anyone else had to struggle with the same thing.

From the top menu select `Window` then `Preferences`, navigate to `General\Appearance\Color and Fonts\Basic`, edit font size in `Text Font`.

Answer (score 1):

... and on a Mac, its the 'Aptana Studio 3' option from the top menu followed by 'Preferences'
then 'General/Appearances/colors & fonts'